# VS2015 header file fails with Error C2864: 'a static data member with an in-class initializer ...'

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

We have a Visual Studio 2010 project that builds ok. I want to migrate the project to Visual Studio 2015.  When I attempt to build the project with VS2015 (toolset 14.0) one of the project's 3rd party source code files fails to compile and gives error:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\tuple(295): error C2864: 'std::tuple<_This,_Rest...>::_Mysize': a static data member with an in-class initializer must have non-volatile const integral type
```

The line of code that is failing is the last line of:

```
template<class _This,
    class... _Rest>
    class tuple<_This, _Rest...>
        : private tuple<_Rest...>
    {   // recursive tuple definition
public:
    typedef _This _This_type;
    typedef tuple<_This, _Rest...> _Myt;
    typedef tuple<_Rest...> _Mybase;
    static constexpr size_t _Mysize = 1 + sizeof...(_Rest);
```

I understand the error message but I don't understand why it occurs for a VS2015 header file. That file should surely be compatible with VS2015 code generation?

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, the project code included the line:

```
#define constexpr /* nothing */
```

I disabled that and the code then compiled.